# Can't find valid JDBC Driver (implementation class) for Hana in Websphere Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty, hana

I'm trying to connect a Websphere Liberty v16.0.0.4 to a HANA datasource, but I'm unable to find the right driver.
Currently in my **server.xml** I have the following:

```xml
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<server description="o01-cls-pega-static-prpc02-appsrv03">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>ejb-3.2</feature>
        <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
        <feature>ejbRemote-3.2</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
        <feature>jaxb-2.2</feature>
        <feature>restConnector-2.0</feature>
        <feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jmsMdb-3.2</feature>
    </featureManager>
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="localhost"
                  httpPort="28740"
                  httpsPort="28741" />

    <!-- JDBC Hana Driver -->
    <jdbcDriver id="myHanaDriver" javax.sql.DataSource="com.ibm.ws.jdbc.jdbcDriver">
        <library>
            <fileset dir="${wlp.user.dir}/shared/resources/hana" includes="*.jar" id="HANALib"/>
        </library>
    </jdbcDriver>
    <!-- HANA JDBC Databases -->
    <dataSource
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              containerAuthDataRef="PegaDBUserSAPHANA"
              id="hanaDataSource"
              jdbcDriverRef="myHanaDriver"
              jndiName="jdbc/hanaDataSource">
    <properties serverName="localhost" port="35315"/>
    </dataSource>
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
</server>
```

This is the error I get:

```
[5/6/19 14:24:24:735 CEST] 00000038 LogService-156-com.ibm.ws.jdbc 
E CWWKE0701E: FrameworkEvent ERROR Bundle:com.ibm.ws.jdbc(id=156) org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: 
Exception in com.ibm.ws.resource.internal.ResourceFactoryTrackerData$1.getService()
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: 
DSRA4000E: A valid JDBC driver implementation class was not found for the jdbcDriver jdbcDriver[myHanaDriver] using the library com.ibm.ws.classloading.sharedlibrary_587. [/opt/wlp/usr/shared/resources/hana/ngdbc.jar]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: 
DSRA4000E: A valid JDBC driver implementation class was not found for the jdbcDriver jdbcDriver[myHanaDriver] using the library com.ibm.ws.classloading.sharedlibrary_587. [/opt/wlp/usr/shared/resources/hana/ngdbc.jar]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.jdbc.jdbcDriver
```

Any one that can help me, get the right implementation class that I need?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `javax.sql.DataSource="com.ibm.ws.jdbc.jdbcDriver"` is misconfigured.  This should either point to the JDBC driver's implementation of javax.sql.DataSource, for example, `javax.sql.DataSource="com.sap.dbtech.jdbcext.DataSourceSapDB"`
or, for many JDBC drivers, newer versions of Liberty (but not the older 16.0.0.4 level that this question asks about) are often able to infer the correct implementation class if you omit this configuration attribute altogether.

Comment: I'm using version 16.0.0.4 because a newer version isn't supported by for the application. Also if we use version 18.0.0.3 the last one I tried, the application isn't working with Chrome.
Question remains what do I need to put here: javax.sql.DataSource="......" com.sap.dbtech.jdbcext.DataSourceSapDB is not working.

Comment: for more details, check out the official doc here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html
specifically, the "For a JDBC driver that is not known to Liberty" section

Comment: also, Liberty has a zero-migration policy, which means that in theory you should be able to upgrade to a newer version of Liberty, and as long as you don't modify the app or config, it should work the same way (except more Liberty bugs will be fixed)

Comment: Regarding "com.sap.dbtech.jdbcext.DataSourceSapDB is not working", what error do you get?  Is it the same error about the implementation class not being found, or something different?  If the class isn't found, you should supply additional information such as what the full JAR name for your JDBC driver and what version it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now, I changed this:
javax.sql.DataSource="com.ibm.ws.jdbc.jdbcDriver"
into 
javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="com.sap.db.jdbcext.ConnectionPoolDataSourceSAP"

And type="javax.sql.DataSource" into this type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource".